# I have trouble resizing multiple images to different dimensions

Tags: css, gridview

I started off a month ago and I have trouble understanding the grid system on CSS.
I can to create some classes on my html to later edit on my CSS but it does not seem to work. I want to add some images so they cover that entire section of the page while other to appear small (images of products I am selling).

Any advice on where to learn this efficiently?

Comment: It might help you if you could provide an example set of code which we can use to illustrate how to get images with the sizes you need. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

I found this reference super helpful when trying to implement a grid.
https://grid.malven.co/

On laying out some images on a grid, it helps me to remember that I can use a combination of different positioning techniques inside the grid boxes. I also found that [this class on css](https://joshwcomeau.com) for developers is super detailed and helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I found this site that brings several examples of using the grid: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

The "grid-template-areas" section seems to provide a solution for what you want, by referencing the names of the grid areas which are specified with the grid-area property. The syntax itself provides a visualization of the structure of the grid.